# What are the sources for every piece of Mass Effect 3 DLC?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I'm lost in the sea of Mass Effect 3 DLC. From what I understand, there are numerous sources for DLC codes that allow access to in-game content like new weapons, skins, maps, missions, etc. These sources include pre-order bonuses from various retailers, Collector's Edition content, purchasable in-game content from the "normal" sources (Xbox Marketplace, Orign, etc.), and many others.

I realize this is an involved question begging for an involved answer, but **what are all the required sources for every piece of in-game content DLC?** Does EA keep a updated list of this information?

As a corollary question, is any of the DLC now unavailable due to the game being past the preorder state or other reasons?

Comment: Steam? I wish...

Comment: I mentioned Steam because I'm assuming the game will eventually come to that platform, although I could be wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a bunch of stuff that is pre-order or only came with the Collector's Edition:

- AT-12 Raider - Origin pre-order bonus
- M-55 Argus - Pre-order bonus for select retailers
- N7 Warfare Gear - Pre-order bonus for select retailers
- Robotic Dog - Collector's edition
- Squad Outfit pack - Collector's edition
- N7 Weapons pack - Collector's edition
- N7 Hoodie - Collector's edition

These are all single player items.  The Collector's edition and pre-order bonuses are currently unavailable outside of pre-ordering the game or buying the collector's edition.  No news on whether or not those of us with the "regular edition" will be able to buy them at a later date.

There's a couple of single player items that you can get for free by playing the Kingdoms of Amalur demo:

- Chakram Launcher
- Reckoner Knight Armor

There's a Battlefield 3 Pack (a set of multiplayer items) that you can only get by having Battlefield 3 activated to the same account as Mass Effect 3.

There's also the "From Dust" DLC (a single player mission + a new squadmate) which came with the deluxe/collectors editions but is available to anyone (from day 1) for around $10.

In addition to these items, there's a number of [Razer ME3-branded items](http://www.razerzone.com/me3) that come with [special codes/unlocks](http://www.joystiq.com/2012/02/16/razers-mass-effect-3-peripherals-include-game-dlc/) for multiplayer.

On top of these, there's a whole set of [Mass Effect 3 toys](http://www.gamespot.com/news/mass-effect-3-toys-to-feature-dlc-retail-radar-6349124) that you can buy, and each one comes with a similar code for multiplayer to the Razer items.

One tally of all the DLC for Mass Effect 3 listed the grand total at [$870](http://kotaku.com/5888816/buying-all-of-mass-effect-3s-dlc-will-cost-you-870)!  However, the codes that come with the Razer gear and the toys are more along the lines of the "booster packs" you can buy in the multiplayer in-game shop, so I wouldn't consider them anywhere approaching essential.

Comment: This is the type of nonsense I cannot stand. Silly silly silly. +1 for a good answer that cleared up my mind :)

Comment: @Cor_Blimey, yeah, and I'm not even 100% sure I got them all.  I forgot the BF3 unlock the first run through, for example...